# How to automatically delete old built archives in xcode continuous integration?

Tags: xcode, build, continuous-integration

I'm using a bot to integrate/build my project with xcode continuous integration. With Jenkins, I can define the max number of builds I want to keep.

Is there a possibility to achieve this with xcode ci with an automated process?

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

The only useable solutions I found so far is using the REST api of the Xcode server.

Basically you write a script to get all the IDs of the old integrations (using the filter API) and then delete them. Trigger the script from a cron job or jenkins.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeServerAPIReference/Integrations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016472-CH3-SW2

Alternative:

Delete all the old integrations from your Xcode server in the file system under /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/IntegrationAssets/

https://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-05-04-under-the-hood-of-xcode-server/

If anyone come up with a easier solutions: I'm all ears.